# Python webscrape export as csv - no data

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have this script that pulls from a website and it doesn't seem to want to write the data to csv. **I'm assuming there's something wrong with my for loop and how it's being told to write it.** Would someone take a look for me and see how you would change it? What am I missing here.

I appreciate your help.

Below is the python script - again, I think the issue is with the for loop at the bottom.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# setting my_url to the wesite
urls = ['https://www.extraspace.com/Storage/Facilities/US/North_Carolina/Charlotte/1000000398/Facility.aspx'
    , 'https://www.extraspace.com/Storage/Facilities/US/North_Carolina/Charlotte/1000000404/Facility.aspx']

filename = "extraspace.csv"
open(filename, 'w').close()
f = open(filename, "a")
num = 0

headers = "unit_size, size_dim1, unit_type, online_price, reg_price, street_address, store_city, store_postalcode\n"

f.write(headers)

for my_url in urls:
    # Opening up connection, grabbing the page
    uClient = uReq(my_url)

    # naming uClient to page_html
    page_html = uClient.read()

    # closing uClient
    uClient.close()

    # this does my html parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    # setting container to capture where the actual info is using inspect element

    #grabs each product
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "makesOffer"})

    #grabs address
    store_locator = page_soup.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "address"})

    f.write("website " + str(num) + ": \n")
    for container in containers:
        for store_location in store_locator:
            street_address = store_location.findAll("span", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"})
            store_city = store_location.findAll("span", {"itemprop": "addressLocality"})
            store_postalcode = store_location.findAll("spand", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})
            title_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "size RamaGothicSemiBold"})
            size_dim = container.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "description"})
            unit_container = container.ul.li
            unit_type = container.text
            online_price = container.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "price"})
            reg_price = container.findAll("div", {"class": "rate strikeout"})

        for item in zip(title_container, size_dim, unit_type, online_price, reg_price, street_address, store_city, store_postalcode):
            csv = item[0].text + "," + item[1].text + "," + item[2] + "," + item[3].text + "," + item[4].text + "," + item[5].text + "," + item[6].text + "," + item[7].text + "\n"
            f.write(csv)
    num += 1
```

This is the HTML for containers:

```html
<div itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <div class="guide">
            <div class="size-help-lnk size-guide hidden" data-locker="False" data-square-feet="25">Size Help</div>
            <div alt="5x5" class="video-btn-5x5 video-link" onclick="trackSC('UnitListingVideo');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="size RamaGothicSemiBold">
            <div itemprop="description">5' x 5'</div>
            <div>SMALL</div>
        </div>
        <div class="features">
            <ul itemprop="description">
                <li><i class="check-icon"></i>Enclosed Storage</li>
                <li><i class="check-icon"></i>Indoor</li>
                <li><i class="check-icon"></i>1st Floor Access</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rate strikeout">
            <div><span style="width:100%;"></span>$57</div><span class="StreetRate">IN-STORE</span></div>
        <div class="rate">
            <div content="35.00" itemprop="price">$35
                <meta content="USD" itemprop="priceCurrency" />
            </div><span class="WebRate">WEB RATE</span></div>
        <div class="promo"><span style="color:#000;">Act fast:<br/>Limited units</span></div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-orange cta-test is-vehicle" href="https://www.extraspace.com/Storage/ReserveOrHold.aspx?uid=a0GC000000tUNupMAG" id="ctl00_mContent_UnitListPopular_ctrl0_hlReserveLink" onclick="upDown('unitRows|8506|1;05X05|NDN|57|35| | ; | | | | | ; | | | | | ;05X05|CDN|71|48| | ;05X07|CDN|74|50| | ');">RESERVE</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <link href="http://schema.org/OnlineOnly" itemprop="availability">
    </link>
</div>
```

Below is the html for the store_locator;

```html
[ < div itemprop = "address"
    itemscope = ""
    itemtype = "http://schema.org/PostalAddress" >
    <
    span id = "ctl00_mContent_lbAddress"
    itemprop = "streetAddress" > 3304 Eastway Dr < br / > Ste D < /span><br/ >
    <
    span id = "ctl00_mContent_lbCity"
    itemprop = "addressLocality" > Charlotte < /span>, <
    span id = "ctl00_mContent_lbState"
    itemprop = "addressRegion" > NC < /span> <
    span id = "ctl00_mContent_lbPostalCode"
    itemprop = "postalCode" > 28205 < /span> <
    /div>]
```

Comment: I think the 4th loop should be nested in the 3rd loop. Also you don't have to `zip` the items, and you should use `csv` to write csv files.

Comment: Could you show me what you mean by the 4th loop being nested in the 3rd and why (trying to understand). Also, for the zip items, I was under the impression if I am going to put several urls to run this loop, it's a good idea to zip the items.

Comment: I attempted to reproduce the issue, but I can't connect to the urls provided.  However, I did use the html you posted.  Basically, your code never gets past the `for store_location in store_locator:` part because `store_locator` is empty, and does not have any contents, at least based here on my reproduction of your code. Try doing a `print("store_locator: " + store_locator)` and check on your end.

All the code below that within the loop does not run. Which means that there really isn't anything to write to csv. What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @ B B - I threw in your print code and received this error: "  File "extra_space_comps.py", line 59, in <module>
    print("store_locator: " + store_locator)
TypeError: must be str, not ResultSet"  I will say though, that my script does work on another website just fine. It's strange that this site (different company) isn't working.

Comment: Hoping someone could help me out with this. Still fairly new to python.

Comment: So is your file empty after you run this? I would suggest you to add f.close() in the end of your script. This might help.

Comment: @ GSazheniuk it gives me a file with the headers in the first row, then in row 2, column 1, "website 0:"   and in row 3, column 1, "website 1:"   but nothing else.

Comment: Still looking for help on this please